# How to accept cookie on the wkhtmltopdf command?

Tags: linux, pdf, cookie

I am using the Linux command `wkhtmltopdf` to convert the HTML page to a PDF file for a report, but the page showing the cookie privacy note on the website which doesn't look good.

To convert the `wkhtmltopdf`, seems the `--cookies-jar` is not a correct command to use.

Please suggest any other way?

[image]

Command used:

```
$ wkhtmltopdf -O Landscape \
     http://example.com/app/viewport.html#/overview/tabular/yearly data.pdf
```